# storing objects in database

Tags: mongodb, object, inheritance, overloading, database

Imagin  a class **A** that has a property **x** and a property **y** and a class **B** that has a property **Z** and inherits all properties from its parent **A**. My Class **Hello** witch is a **B** and  now should have access to all properties from **A** and **B**. Each Property can be overritten in each stage.

Inheritance and overloading/overriding - but i want to store such objects within kind  a database and have r/w access via a simple api.

any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Read the [driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) docs for whatever language matches your needs. There may be an object layer that provides this support you want. It's a schema-less document DB, so it's app design that will enforce your needs, not MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is document-oriented and can save data as objects and arrays. 
You must write functions for converting data from/to mongodb to your object structure and use it.

[this link Show you how to Save Object into DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405106/inserting-a-php-object-into-a-mongo-db)